# Why the background doesn't work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is the page: http://aszx.altervista.org/aatest/

As you can see from the source code, the #news, #news-1 and #news-2 have this rule:
 `background: #F2F2F2;`

Could you tell me why the background doesn't change and it's still white ?

I have noticed that the background change when I resize the browser's window.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  Although you have provided a link if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the floats are causing the div to not be of any height. You need to add a `clearfix` class to the elements you're trying to set the background to.

```
<div class="col-md-10 center-block clearfix" id="news">
```

This will cause the `#news` div to clear itself, thus making its height encompass the contained div elements. Do the same for your other containing elements as well.